# Problems about distribution of java project

Tags: java, filepath, software-distribution

I am completely new to programming and I am now doing a project that I need to read a specific XML file in java. My code is using the absolute path of the file I need but I have to distribute the project to somewhere. That required XML file will not be in the project folder but in another folder which I will distribute with the JAR file of the project. Is it possible for it to get that path if I don't know where the user will put my program and the folder containing the XML file?

The program is supposed to run on Windows.

Comment: Are you using an interface (swing or other) ? You can always look for FileChooserDialog (or something like this) to let the user point at the file. But you can always distribute your jar in a archive (zip) with the xml

Comment: You need to ask from the user in your code, as to where have they put the xml file!

Comment: This is exactly why you should avoid using hard-coded absolute paths. Either use relative path to a File, if the File is outside of your jar, or use relative path to class resources, if the xml is within the jar file. This has been asked and answered many times on this site, and you will want to search this site a bit to check out these duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the problem. I raise my own question here because I have no idea what I should search with. So I should either let the user choose the file himself with a FileChooser, or not let the user choose a file, but change the code that to a relative path that resources.

Comment: Will the xml file be changeable? Or is it stable? Will it reside within the jar file?

Comment: One force you to trust the user on his input (or validate the file using a xsd)  the second is easier but prevent you to change the file in the futur (well, it is possible ..)

Comment: Hovercraft, the file is changeable. Therefore I can't put it inside the jar.

Answer (score 0):

You have different possible solutions:

- pass the file location as parameter to the `main` method (if you have a `main` method)
- set an [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) with the location of the file (you can do that with the `-D` option on the java command, with the syntax `-Dproperty=value`)
- set an environment variable (with `export` command in linux)
- put the file in the classpath and retrieve it with [`getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))
- access the file from an external server exposing it via HTTP

Comment: don't forget environment variables `System.getenv(String)`